# AngularJS defer return until completed

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to build a service that will return a **$resource** after the service has authenticated.
I have done it like this:

```
.factory('MoltinApi', ['$q', '$resource', '$http', 'moltin_options', 'moltin_auth', function ($q, $resource, $http, options, authData) {
    var api = $resource(options.url + options.version + '/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    var authenticate = function () {
        if (!options.publicKey)
            return;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: options.url + 'oauth/access_token',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: "grant_type=implicit&client_id=" + options.publicKey
        };

        $http(request).success(function (response) {
            authData = response;

            deferred.resolve(api);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return authenticate();
}])
```

But I can not call the resource in my controller:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['MoltinApi', function (moltin) {
    var self = this;

    moltin.get({ path: 'categories' }, function (categories) {
        console.log(categories);
    });
}]);
```

it just states that 'undefined is not a function'.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Update 1**

So after playing with the solution that was suggested, this is the outcome.

```
angular.module('moltin', ['ngCookies'])

// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.factory('MoltinApi', ['$cookies', '$q', '$resource', '$http', 'moltin_options', function ($cookies, $q, $resource, $http, options) {
    var api = $resource(options.url + options.version + '/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    var authenticate = function () {
        if (!options.publicKey)
            return;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var authData = angular.fromJson($cookies.authData);

        if (!authData) {
            console.log('from api');
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: options.url + 'oauth/access_token',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: "grant_type=implicit&client_id=" + options.publicKey
            };

            deferred.resolve($http(request).success(function (response) {
                $cookies.authData = angular.toJson(response);
                setHeaders(response.access_token);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log('from cookie');
            deferred.resolve(setHeaders(authData.access_token));
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var setHeaders = function (token) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }

    return authenticate().then(function (response) {
        return api;
    });
}]);
```

and to call it I have to do this:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['MoltinApi', function (moltin) {
    var self = this;

    moltin.then(function (api) {
        api.get({ path: 'categories' }, function (categories) {
            console.log(categories);
            self.sports = categories.result;
        });
    });
}]);
```

but what I would like to do is this:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['MoltinApi', function (moltin) {
    var self = this;

    moltin.get({ path: 'categories' }, function (categories) {
        console.log(categories);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

As you can see, the service is checking to see if we have authenticated before returning the API. Once it has authenticated then the API is returned and the user can then call the api without having to authenticate again. 
Can someone help me refactor this service so I can call it without having to **moltin.then()**?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the authenticate function call in the MoltinApi factory, so you are returning the promise. And the method get doesn't exist in the promise

Comment: so how can I return the api $resource "after" the authentication has succeeded or failed?

Comment: return instead the authenticate function, but don't call it, and in the controller call it. I don't see that you need the $resource service if you are using the $http service. Use one, $http or $resource

Comment: I don't want to call the authenticate function in the controller. I want it to authenticate when the service is instantiated before any other calls are made.

Comment: Ok, so call it and return the api variable then you can access the get method

Comment: I harcoded everything because i am missing some of your services (options, etc) http://plnkr.co/edit/BoS7IWdUQKov3dUer9De?p=preview

Comment: Your approach is quite valid i just couldn't understand it at the beginning. Because i would separate it in two services.

Comment: so what you are showing is that this has to be done for every single request. I would like it if it could be done for the first request only.

Comment: I updated the plunker too, I hpe now is more useful http://plnkr.co/edit/BoS7IWdUQKov3dUer9De?p=preview